# Linux mutex priority inherit

Tags: linux, multithreading

I'm working with Linux mutex for protect share data in multithread application.
For preventing the priority inversion, I use PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT protocol (http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol).
My system have three threads:
thread 1 : low priority, acquire mutex first
thread 2: the same priority with thread 1. No access share data.
thread 3: high priority. acquire mutex after thread 1

Assume that thread 1 is created and run first, then it will lock share data.
thread 3 then create and run, after a milisencond, it acquire lock that thread 1 is owning. So thread 3 is blocked.
At  PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT protocol, priority of thread 1 will raise to priority of thread 3.
After thread 1 release the lock, then thread 3 will run and finish.
So, my question is: which thread is run next, thread 1 or thread 2?

Anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html):

> If there are threads blocked on the mutex object referenced by mutex
> when `pthread_mutex_unlock()` is called, resulting in the mutex
> becoming available, the scheduling policy shall determine which thread
> shall acquire the mutex.

That statement is effectively saying the implementation is free to wake up whichever thread it wants to.

However, for Linux the scheduler policies can be found here:  http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html

Note that that Linux man page makes no mention of mutexes at all.

If your code depends upon a specific wake up order, one simple mutex is the wrong synchronization object to use.

Comment: Thank you.  
But, In my question, thread 1 and thread 2 are not blocked by mutex any more. They are in ready queue, and wait thread 3 finish.  
My problem is: after thread 1 release the mutex to thread 3, which position is thread 1 replaced in ready queue(before thread 2 or behind thread 2)?